# Handle event on childnode click of treeview control using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I created an ASP.NET page and placed a `<asp:TreeView>` on it, when end user clicks on a child node like `subject:mechanical` then another page should be displayed in same page.

How should I get this using jQuery?

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows">
    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Checked="True" Expanded="False" Text="Stream" Value="Stream">
        <asp:TreeNode Expanded="False" Text="Ploytechnic" Value="Ploytechnic">
        <asp:TreeNode Expanded="False" Text="Subject" Value="Subject">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Mechanical" Value="Mechanical"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="IT/CS" Value="IT/CS"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Chemical" Value="Chemical"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Civil" Value="Civil"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="ENTC" Value="ENTC"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="EE" Value="EE"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Expanded="False" Text="B.E." Value="B.E.">
        <asp:TreeNode Expanded="False" Text="Subject" Value="Subject">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Mechanical" Value="Mechanical"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="IT/CS" Value="IT/CS"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Chemical" Value="Chemical"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Civil" Value="Civil"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="ENTC" Value="ENTC"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="EE" Value="EE"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: You should consider to try something on your side before asking other people how to write it for you. Or consider to tell us where are you stuck?!

Comment: Note: if you are posting ASP code and then talking about using jQuery on it, you're asking the wrong question. jQuery doesn't care about the serverside code, only your rendered HTML.